# Area screenshot - move crosshair with keyboard

Tags: screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I know that there is already the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd> to take a screenshot of a specific area. In this way the pointer changes into a crosshair and you have to click & drag to select the area you want for the screenshot.

But I'm more like a keyboard kind of guy, so I'd like to move around the crosshair with my keyboard. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can control the mouse with the direction keys if you have a numeric keypad.

Open `Dash` using the <kbd>Super Key</kbd> and type `Universal Access`:

[image: Mouse Keys]

As shown above select the `Pointing and Clicking` tab and set the `Mouse Keys` to "ON".

Now when you have <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> toggled off the arrow keys will move the mouse pointer.

**NOTE:** On my system it was slow moving the cursor with the arrow keys so I'll still use the mouse to move around faster.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Indeed, it seems really really slow.

Comment: It also seems to disable the shortcuts such as ` Alt-Ctrl-Numpad` used to place current window at a specific location.

Comment: Yup it's painfully slow... however it could be handy fine tuning to reach an exact pixel.